# What am i doing wrong? Each board I use the jointer on leaves them not even. P

Tags: jointer

What am i doing wrong? Each board I use the jointer on leaves them not even. They are 12w x 1t and 50 inches long. Can they be fixed.

Sincerely,
Ann

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange but we need more detail about what the problem is exactly, in what way(s) are they not even? Also, SE requires that Questions are posed after a good attempt has been made to find the solution elsewhere, see the third bullet point [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: *"What am i doing wrong?"* Hard to guess without the requested additional details, but it sounds like perhaps you're trying to do this on the jointer only? If so that's it. In the usual process these days the jointer is used in concert with a saw and a planer to produce two parallel edges and two parallel faces, AKA "four square", The workflow often being: joint the 1st face, then joint an edge square to that prepared face (hence the tall fence on jointers, to run the face along). Then the planer for uniform thickness, then the 2nd edge is sawn parallel to the first using the TS and its fence.

Comment: As Graphus said, we could use a little more info on what you mean by 'not even'  each answer will have a different suggestion on how to fix the problem.

Comment: What size jointer are you using? For a 12" wide board you'd normally use a jointer that's at least that wide, and machines that big aren't all that common in home shops.

Comment: Please tell us more details about what you're doing now, how you're doing it, and what kind of problems you're seeing. What do you mean by _"leaves them not even"_? What's not even? The width? Thickness?

Comment: I'm adding a second vote to close as the body of the Question is missing all the needed details to provide an on-point Answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you're having trouble getting even results with a jointer, there are several potential issues that could be at play.  Here are some common problems and their solutions that you might want to consider:

1. **Improper Feeding:** Make sure that you are feeding the boards evenly and at a consistent speed.  If the board is fed unevenly, it can result in an uneven cut.
2. **Machine Setup:** The jointer itself may not be set up properly.  Ensure that the knives are set at the correct height and are parallel to the outfeed table.  The tables should be flat and parallel to each other.
3. **Knife Wear:** If the knives are dull or have uneven wear, they may not cut evenly.  Sharpen or replace the knives as needed.
4. **Table Cleanliness:** Dirt or debris on the tables can cause the wood to slip, leading to an uneven cut.  Keep the tables clean and ensure they are free of dust and other particles.
5. **Wood Moisture:** If the wood is too dry or too wet, it can affect the jointing process.  Wood should have a moisture content of around 8-10% for best results.
6. **Poor Support:** Ensure that the board is well supported during the jointing process.  This may involve using push sticks or other supports to keep the board flat and steady against the table.
7. **Material Defects:** The boards themselves may have defects such as warping, cupping, or bowing, which can make it difficult to achieve an even cut.

If your boards are not coming out even after going through the jointer, it's important to identify the cause of the issue and address it.  In some cases, the boards may be too cupped or bowed to be fixed with the jointer alone.  You may need to use a planer to flatten the boards first, and then use the jointer to edge them.  If the boards are cupped, you might also try using a hand plane to plane the concave side to make it flat before running them through the jointer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange and Woodworking. Thanks for adding a generalised Answer that covers a range of possible issues. Re. your 5 though, this is much too generic to really be useful. These figures are often given for the US, covering a range of climate types, but even there it generally covers wood for indoor projects only; unfortunately we don't even know from the OP if that's what they are prepping. Even if we focus on furniture wood these figures might not apply to Canada, and are lower than desirable for the British Isles, as well as parts of Australia with year-round high humidity.

Comment: This has the vague feeling of ChatGPT/AI to it.